# Is it possible to delete a monitor or change the name as shown in Display Preferences?

Tags: display

I have a pair of the same model and size monitors at home, as I have in the office. They're all named "Company Model (1)" and "Company Model (2)".

It seems like the setup I have at home has them physically arranged from L -> R: 1 -> 2, but in the office, however, it's 2 -> 1.

The result is when I work from home, or work from the office, I need to constantly set the Display Arrangement in Preferences.

Is there a way to delete the displays, so I can reintroduce them to the computer in the right order, or just rename them so the one physically on the left is always 1, and the one on the right is always 2?

Comment: I could theoretically delete the Displays in .GlobalPreferences.list, but I'm worried about breaking the file.

Comment: Couldn't you just take the two displays in either location and switch their physical ordering so that the computer's understanding is correct? Or am I missing something...

Comment: @ToddDabney We're all missing something, because I did exactly that, and it doesn't seem to matter. I thought it had to do with the naming, but there seems to be some weird configuration based on assumptions that you're never going to have the same make and model of monitors in two different places.

Comment: Do I need to reset the pram or smc or something maybe, then plug in the monitors in the same order from location to the other?

Comment: Spencer I'm not understanding how what you're describing is possible. What you stated originally was that it was consistently one way at home and the opposite way at the office. So switching the monitors would easily solve this, but you're saying that when you switched the physical location of the monitors they then started consistently showing up in the opposite orientation, leaving you with the same problem?

Comment: Yeah, it's _bizarre_. I really don't get it. I'm going to reset the nvram, and connect the monitors in the same orientation in both locations. Maybe that will solve it.

Comment: When you switched the monitor locations did you switch the cables as well? It's possible that it's the cable length that's determining which gets connected first since this would lead to a tiny but possibly perceptible difference in sync time.

Comment: @ToddDabney points for using physics as a possible explanation. :-D I have the MBP with USB-C connectors and no dock, so I don't connect them at the same time, and the ordering in which I connect the USB-C adapters doesn't make a difference (one of the first things I tried).

Comment: I think I'm on to something. I'm using two different USB-C adapters for HDMI, one is powered and has USB3 ports, and the other is just a straight HDMI - USB-C adapter. I'm using the same model HDMI - USB-C adapter in the office and at home. When I switched the *HDMI* inputs between the two adapters, it changed the arrangement! I need to go into the office and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's the dongle with which the monitors are connected. I have two different brands (Satechi and Anker) at home, and (Apple and Anker) at work. When I plug the monitors into the different dongles, it changes orientation. The reason the physical swap didn't work, was because I also unplugged the cables from the monitors in the office, and reconnected them to the different dongles. I tried unplugging the monitors from the dongles at home and swapping them, and and they indeed switched.

This is probably the most trivial of information, but it's at least answered!